# Mail don't reach server

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, domain, email-server, mx-record

I have VPS and serve several domains.

DNS/MX config should be ok, as for *.com domains mails are both sent and received.

Problem is with my country domain - *.hr (Croatia) - mails are sent, but replied/new mail never reach my server (even tail -f log but nothing happens).

MX records are standard - mail.domain-name.com/hr

Can it be something specific with country domain?

Thanks,
Vedran newbie in server world

### EDITED:

Site is prva-liga.hr
http://www.intodns.com/prva-liga.hr
ERROR: Some of your DNS servers do not have A records at all. I could not find any A records for the following DNS servers:
ns2.tkojemile.com
ns1.tkojemile.com

You must have A records for all of your nameservers.

But let's say for *.com domain mivean.com - all works really fine with same configuration.
http://www.intodns.com/mivean.com

Don't have a clue even when reading tons of content on this issues.

Thanks,
Vedran

### ADITIONAL DATA:

Zone file:

```
$TTL 10800
@ IN SOA prva-liga.hr.    postmaster.prva-liga.hr. (
    2014101409  ;serial
    21600    ;refresh after 6 hours
    3600    ;retry after 1 hour
    604800   ;expire after 1 week
    86400 )    ;minimum TTL of 1 day
@    3600    IN    A    130.255.191.162
mail    86400    IN    A    130.255.191.162
ns1    172800    IN    A    130.255.191.162
ns2    172800    IN    A    130.255.191.162
www    3600    IN    CNAME   @
ftp    3600    IN    CNAME   @
cp    86400    IN    CNAME   @
@    86400    IN    MX    10  mail.prva-liga.hr.
@    172800    IN    NS    ns1.tkojemile.com.
@    172800    IN    NS    ns2.tkojemile.com.
```

Comment: Please name the domain in question.

Comment: This is zone file: http://www.speedyshare.com/HTt2A/zones.txt

Comment: Please don't force us to navigate through an adware-ridden file sharing site. Edit your question and include relevant portions of your file.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I posted zone file in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that neither of your listed name servers actually exist.

Who serves `.hr`?

```
[me@risby ~]$ dig ns hr.
[...]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
hr.                     14400   IN      NS      dns-hr.univie.ac.at.
hr.                     14400   IN      NS      sns-pb.isc.org.
hr.                     14400   IN      NS      pch.carnet.hr.
hr.                     14400   IN      NS      hr-ns-1.carnet.hr.
hr.                     14400   IN      NS      n3ns.nic.es.
```

OK, let's ask one of them who serves `prva-liga.hr`:

```
[me@risby ~]$ dig ns prva-liga.hr. @pch.carnet.hr.
[...]
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
prva-liga.hr.           14440   IN      NS      ns2.tkojemile.com.
prva-liga.hr.           14440   IN      NS      ns1.tkojemile.com.
```

OK, let's ask them about your MX record:

```
[me@risby ~]$ dig mx prva-liga.hr @ns1.tkojemile.com.
dig: couldn't get address for 'ns1.tkojemile.com.': not found
[me@risby ~]$ dig mx prva-liga.hr @ns2.tkojemile.com.
dig: couldn't get address for 'ns2.tkojemile.com.': not found
```

I don't know who's supposed to be providing `tkojemile.com`'s DNS infrastructure, but they're not doing a very good job.  Once you pick some working nameservers, the internet should be able to find your mail server, and the mail should flow.  Until you fix this, it won't.

I take your point about `mivean.com` working, but that's a happy accident, caused by both `tkojemile.com` and `mivean.com` being under `.com`.  When recursing down to the `MX` record for `mivean.com.`, the nameservers for `.com` are passing addresses for `ns[12].tkojemile.com` back as part of the glue.  Queries for zones in `.hr` don't touch the `.com` servers, and don't get that handy glue.

Comment: thanks a lot! :)
I completely forgot to add tkojemile domain and dns data to my server. Now it works fine. Thanks once again, you opened my eyes :)

Answer (score 1):

Its very difficult to debug the problem without knowing more, but the steps you might take would be :

1. Do a DNS lookup on the MX record for the .hr domain (for example, from a linux box - "dig @8.8.8.8 domainname.hr mx") which will tell you the MX record for the domain.  Make sure the MX records ends with a "." - for example mail.domainname.com. would be correct where mail.domainname.com would not be - common mistake.

Once you know the dns record for the domain, telnet to it on port 25 like so: "telnet mail.domainname.hr"   (no . at the end here) and see if you get a "Helo banner" from your server.   If not, then you should start looking at your firewall if the IP resolves correctly, or your DNS record if it doesn't.

You may also want to use "tcpdump -n port 25" when trying to send mail to your server to see if there is a connection attempt to your mail server.  This will tell if the mail traffic is actually getting to your server but being ignored by Postfix.

Comment: This is output:
[root@server ~]# dig 8.8.8.8 prva-liga.hr mx

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1 <<>> @8.8.8.8 prva-liga.hr mx
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 28526
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;prva-liga.hr.                  IN      MX

;; Query time: 153 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Wed Oct 15 17:09:24 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 30